# Input text-overflow: ellipsis; for Opera and IE does not work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opera

I am trying to use text-overflow: ellipsis for my inputs but only chrome and Firefox shows it fines. On IE and opera it does not make any effect. Is there any hack..

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SZYFw/

```
input {
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}

<pre>
   <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.">​
</pre>
```

opera version: 12.11 Build 1661
ie version: 10

​

Comment: Without any code, it is hard!

Comment: can you share your code and IE opera version information

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work with a DIV [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SZYFw/2/) with all compatibilities, but, unfortunately, see what it says for **input** elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771795/how-to-use-text-overflow-ellipsis-in-an-html-input-field)...

Compatibility for Opera:

```
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Also see this [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/). I think it's not supported for Opera and IE... But as you can see, the rest works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

By the [CSS Basic U](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#text-overflow)I draft, `text-overflow` “specifies rendering when inline content overflows its block container”. But an `input` element has no content; it has a value, which is displayed, but the value is not element content.

For considering a workaround, please specify the context and purpose of using ellipsis for input text. Normal implementations of `input type=text` automatically scroll the value horizontally if needed, and a user can be expected to see that he reaches the end of the input box.

Comment: I use input elements to show names of items like a windows folder name and also want that user can edit, and want to show ... if the name is clipped..

Comment: @karanba, so why would it need the ellipsis? If you think it is really needed, set up a `div` element with `contenteditable` attribute and (if the data is to be submitted as part of a form) copy its content into a hidden field when submitting the form (via `onsubmit` handler).

Comment: I think there is no way out to do this with input:text fiels. I will try is to use div or span at view time and suddenly change it to text when user click on it for change.. like @Jukka K. Korpela offers

Answer (score -1):

#### Assuming you have no code, ellipsis doesn't work.

See if your code matches to this:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
word-wrap: normal;
max-width: 130px;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mmQm/

This works in IE 7, IE 8, IE 9, IE 10, Firefox, Chrome

Comment: The question was about `input`. Your fiddle has `span`. Changed to use `input`, it does not work on IE: http://jsfiddle.net/FgyYb/

Comment: Okie. Anyways, this answer wouldn't help. Will try something.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has not gotten much attention. I have been struggling for some time to make ellipsis work on IE (8&9) and was missing word-wrap: normal.

All other answers/blogs on the Web give answers that don't really work on IE. I know it's late but thanks.

Comment: @Praveen, glad to hear it, but that’s not the question.

Comment: @danorton Fine, I will correct my answer. Will you remove the downvote?

Comment: The theory is that `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is what you need. However, that doesn't work for `input` elements in IE, and that's what this question is about, and that's what this answer does _not_ answer.