# How to make input element text-overflow:ellipsis on IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I found my

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/bcnLzw79/) 
only work on Chrome and FF, I don't know why it don't have the ellipsis effect on IE? Hope someone can help on this, it would be better if you can solve it by a CSS way.

BTW, It seems the div has text-overflow:ellipsis effect on both IE and Chrome.

css:

```
.ellip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" class="ellip" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
<div class="ellip">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
```

Comment: ok. I'll update the code into the question.t The reason i provided a fiddle here is for you to directly open it to see the different behavior in IE and Chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use text-overflow ellipsis in an html input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771795/how-to-use-text-overflow-ellipsis-in-an-html-input-field)

Comment: @KawineshSK This one seems doesn't have a solution...

Comment: @huanfeng there is a reason why it doesnt have a solution which is expained there

Comment: @KawineshSK Sorry, I don't read that there. Really, this is a similar question but explicitly about IE, this is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: @KawineshSK so we don't a solution in IE? BTW, the accept answer in your link doesn't say it worked well in Chrome...

Comment: @SharathDaniel IE version 11

Answer (score 1):

```
.ellip:before {
content: ''; /* IE9 ellipsis fix */
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/svdbco/s1x0qx1a/

**IE8 screenshot**:

[image]

**IE11 screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: it worked for button in your screenshot, but it doesn't work for input type="text" element.

Answer (score -3):

what effect you expect to see???

use this and see effect:

```
.ellip {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    -ms-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
 }
```

Comment: I need the ellipsis effect

Comment: what is your browser version?? it work in IE version 6 to upper

Comment: I don't need the clip effect, i need the ellipsis effect, IE version 11